# Jailbreak Detection Flutter Apps

Tags: flutter, dart, jailbreak

I have added the Jail break detection for my Flutter app where I have used the below dependency,

```
trust_fall: ^1.0.4
```

So Its working as expected I have tested in the nox emulator outcome is app is crashing while opening that is what is expected and got the same. For this trust_fall dependency will require  `minSdkVersion 18`  value should be over 16 in build.gradle.

But when I tried in the real device the app is crashing. So I commented the trust_fall dependency in pubspec.yaml and changed the minsdkVersion back to 16 then it opened correctly no crash.

I want to have Jailbreak check but its crashing in the real device, Any Solution for this??

Comment: It looks like this package is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out other packages like flutter_jailbreak_detection and ing_app_security. These packages are updated.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the other available packages

Comment: Hi @Yash, have you used the ing_app_security package? I am getting this while adding that package:The current Flutter SDK version is 1.16.3.

Because comviva depends on ing_app_security any which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.20.0, version solving failed.

Comment: upgrade your Flutter SDK version to 1.20.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try [freeRASP](https://pub.dev/packages/freerasp) on pub.dev. This package is alive and supported (I am the contributor).